# how to sign and send multiple transactions with single confirmation click of wallet popup?

Tags: anchor, wallet, umi

I am aware of adding multiple instructions to a single transaction. But for my use case one transaction is not enough. I have created and signed multiple transactions but don't know how to send it at once.
Here's my code. I am using umi library.

```
let splitTxBuilders = txBuilder.unsafeSplitByTransactionSize(umi);
const splitTxs = await Promise.all(
    splitTxBuilders.map(
        async builder => await builder.buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi)
    )
);
const signedTxs = await user.signAllTransactions(splitTxs);
console.log({ signedTxs });
```

when i try to send each transaction like this the wallet doesn't popup.

```
for (const signedTx of signedTxs) {
    await umi.rpc.sendTransaction(signedTx, {
        skipPreflight: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding the unexpected behaviour? The first snippet of code looks good but I'm not sure what the `user` variable refers to and, most importantly, I don't know what error or unexpected behaviour your get when running it.